# Binomial Distribution of hitting target

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The probability of a person hitting a target is 1/4.

1.) If they fire five times, what is the probability of hitting the target exactly four times?

2.) What is the probability of hitting the target at least twice?

My attempts:

1.) With the formula

[image]

where n = 5, k = 4, p = 1/4, I got 0.0146

2.) I did the same thing but this time k  = 2 and got 0.2637. But this is wrong. So my question is how do I find the probability of this.

Comment: For 2, since it asks you for the probability you hit the target at least twice, you need to sum the probabilities of the target being hit exactly twice, exactly three times, exactly four times, and exactly five times.

Comment: For 2), a possibly easier way is to find the probability you hit _less_ than twice, that is, add the probability of zero hits to the probability of exactly one hit, and subtract from $1$.

Comment: oh wow. Thanks! That was very simple.

Answer (score 1):

The kick? "At least." The PMF (probability mass function) for a binomial distribution with parameters $n, p,$ is

$$ P(X = x) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}. $$

Now, to get the right answer, you need

$$ P(X \geq 2) = \sum_{j=2}^{5} \binom{5}{j} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^j \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) ^{5-j}. $$

Can you take it from here, champ? You got it!

(Of course the quicker kill is $P(X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X \leq 1)$, but either way works.)

Comment: Thank You very much. I got it now.